# Detecting \global, \long, \outer, \protected

Tags: macros, tex-core, e-tex

Is there a way to detect whether or not the next assignment is going to be `\global`, `\long`, `\outer`, or `\protected`?  That is, is it possible to write a command `\detectmodifiers` such that code like

```
\def\otherdef{%
  \detectmodifiers
  preprocessing
  \ifglobal\expandafter\global\fi
  \iflong\expandafter\long\fi
  \ifouter\expandafter\outer\fi
  \ifprotected\expandafter\protected\fi
  \def
}
```

does the right thing (defines an `\otherdef` command that acts the same way as `\def`, but does some preprocessing first)?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What kind of preprocessing do you have in mind?

Comment: @egrep: He wants to detect if his `\otherdef` was preceded by a `\global` etc. modifier. So when the user is writing `\global\otherdef\macro{<code>}` it can pass the `\global` to the underlying `\def` while having some code before that.

Comment: not very sure if I understood the logic behind your question. If not what you are after pls post a comment and I will clarify or delete my post.

Comment: I'm not really clear on where the 'underlying `\def`' comes from.  The TeX modifiers all allow expansion, so it is possible to have things lit `\def\example{\let\a\b}` and have `\global\example` work correctly.

Comment: The kind of preprocessing I had in mind included defining other commands.  In particular, I'm playing with writing some code that localizes `\global` to a particular group (so that `{\let\foo=a {\localizeglobal {\global\let\foo=b}\show\foo }\show\foo}` gives `b` for the first show and `a` for the second show.).  So I want to be able to play around with defining other macros before a given `\def` is run.  (Though I may end up deciding that the easiest solution is to parse the arguments to `\def` (or `\otherdef`), execute `\def` first, and then use `\let` as I need to.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a dummy `\def` inside `\detectmodifiers` which will be affected by any of the mentioned modifiers if its at the beginning of the macro. Then you can test for the modifiers to build the `if`-switches. You can use `\meaning` on a dummy macro which contains the `\outer`, `\long` and `\protected` modifiers as string which can be extracted and turned into macros again using `\scantokens`.
One challenge would be `\global`: you need to make the assignment in a group and check if it is still the same after the group.

You should use the `if`-tree you have but rather define a macro `\themodifiers` which is then put in front of `\def`:
 `\def\themodifiers{\protected\global}` ... `\themodifiers\def...`.

---

Here some proof-of-concept code. I remembered that the "modifiers" are called prefixes, so I changed the macro names. The prefixes are stored in the `\theprefixes` macro which can be used in front of `\def`. The `\global` prefix however is special and can't be read like this. I tried to define the `\dummy` macro inside a group and use `\global\let\gdummy\dummy` so that I can test if both are still the same after the end of the group. The problem is: a `\begingroup` or `{` isn't allowed before the `\def\dummy` :-(

You should change the names of some macros to prevent name clashes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\macroother{macro}
\@onelevel@sanitize\macroother
\makeatother

\expandafter
\def\expandafter\returnprefixes\expandafter#\expandafter1\macroother#2\relax{%
    \scantokens{\def\theprefixes{#1}}%
}

\def\detectprefixes{%
    \def\dummy{}%
    \expandafter\returnprefixes\meaning\dummy\relax
}

\def\otherdef{%
    \detectprefixes
    % other code
    \theprefixes\def
}

\global\long\outer\protected\otherdef\mymacro{mystuff}
\show\mymacro


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that the only way to detect `\global` is to redefine `\global` to do something like `\detectprefixes\globaltrue\afterassignment\globalfalse\global\theprefixes`. The problem is that this breaks `\afterassignment`. To repair this, we need to redefine `\afterassignment` to store its token using `\futurelet\afterassignmenttoken\afterassignmentaux`, then have `\afterassignmentaux` emit a true `\afterassignment` (so that it still works for other assignments). We also don't want the `\dummy` definition to trigger `\afterassignment`...

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the differences by building a series of conditionals.

```
\def\Z{This}
\global\def\X{This}
\outer\def\Y{This}

\ifx\Z\Y true \else false \fi
```

The `\ifx` will only return true if the two tokens are macros, and they both
have the same status with respect to `\long` and `\outer`, and they both have the same
parameters and "top level" expansion. Based on the conditional you can the build the command using `csname`.

Comment: `\Y` is not allowed inside a macro because it is `\outer`. Maybe `\csname Y\endcsname` will work?

Comment: @Martin I was thinking something as `\modifier\macrofactorymodifier\macroname\definition`. This would call a command `macrofactory` after the group who does the checks against `macrofactorymodifier` and defines the command. `macrofactory` should be `outer` and `long`. I am failing to see the benefits though of defining the command straight or passing a flag.

Comment: One benefit of this is that you can have complex definition macros like `\newcommand` which do a lot before they finally define the macro, but still can use the normal prefixes/modifiers in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Instead of writing a command that does some funny stuff to detect whether `\global` or another prefix came before, modify `\global` etc. to look ahead and use a protocol to inform the appropriate macro that it is to consider itself prefixed.

The following is not working code and is intended to suggest an approach

```
\let\ea\expandafter
\makeatletter

\let\@global\global
\let\@long\long
% etc
\let\@def\def
\let\@edef\edef
% etc
\let\@let\let

\@def\@prefixables{%
    \def%
    \edef%
    % etc
    \let%
}

\@def\newprefixable#1{
    \@def\prefixable@def@reset{
        \ea\@def\csname prefixable@#1@global\endcsname{0}
        \ea\@def\csname prefixable@#1@long\endcsname{0}
        % etc
    }
    \@def\prefixable@def@reset
    \@edef\@prefixables{%
        \expandonce{\@prefixables}%
        \expandonce{\csname#1\endcsname}%
    }
}

\def\global{%
    % Pseudocode
    If the next token is in \@prefixables:
        \@def\prefixable@<the token>@global{1}
    End if
}

\newprefixable{def}
% Showing only treatment of \global
\@def\def#1#2{%
    \if\prefixable@def@global1%
        \@global\@def#1#2%
    \else%
        \@def#1#2%
    \fi%
    \prefixable@def@reset%
}
\newprefixable\otherdef % The macro in the question

\makeatother
```

Additional considerations: It needs to work if more than one prefix comes before a command, e.g. if something like `\long\global\otherdef` happens. This isn't handled by the above

Comment: This will break almost every usage of `\global`: try `\global\dimen1=1cm`, no matter how you redefine `\global`. See Bruno' comment to Martin's answer; and note that the syntax rules say that `\global` triggers expansion of the following token.