# \settowidth problem in tikz and in groups

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, debugging

I just came to the following problem - using `\settowidth` on a length in a `tikzpicture` resets that length to 0? Here is a (totally command-line) MWE, compiled with `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mypgVTitleWidth}
\newbox\tbxa

\setlength{\mypgVTitleWidth}{1.0pt}
\typeout{ = A: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }

\ %

\settowidth{\mypgVTitleWidth}{MMMMM}
\typeout{ = B: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }

\setbox\tbxa\hbox{{MMMMM}}
\mypgVTitleWidth\wd\tbxa
\typeout{ = B2: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }


\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
\ %
\settowidth{\mypgVTitleWidth}{MMMMM}
\typeout{ = C: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }

{

\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
\ %
\settowidth{\mypgVTitleWidth}{MMMMM}
\typeout{ = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }

}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\typeout{ = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }

\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
\ %
\settowidth{\mypgVTitleWidth}{MMMMM}
\typeout{ = F: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### first problem

With that code, with `tikzpicture`, the following log is generated:

```
 = A: \mypgVTitleWidth is 1.0pt
 = B: \mypgVTitleWidth is 53.83278pt
 = B2: \mypgVTitleWidth is 53.83278pt
 = C: \mypgVTitleWidth is 45.83344pt

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <30> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 30.

 = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
 = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is 45.83344pt
 = F: \mypgVTitleWidth is 0.0pt
```

Notably, trace F shows 0.0pt. Comment out the begin and end `tikzpicture` - and this shows in the log:

```
 ...
 = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
 = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is 45.83344pt
 = F: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
```

... as expected.

### second problem

If I use \fontsize..\selectfont in a group to make temporary changes to calculate a length; I get one length inside the `{...}` group - and the previous as soon as I exit:

```
 = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
 = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is 45.83344pt
```

... Ok, this I guess is the very purpose of the group (to make sure changes are local) - but if I wanted to save this length for using further on in the code (say in the tikzpicture), what would I do? I tried also with second `\newlength` set to 0 and `\addtolength`, that resets itself as well.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to: get `\settowidth` working also in `tikz?` - and read `\settowidth` from groups?

Comment: In the `tikzpicture` environment the current font is `nullfont`, which has no characters. Look for `nullfont` on this site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As explained in [How can I use an hbox inside a TikZ environment for text dimension measurement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18606/2975) PGF/TikZ sets the current font inside a picture environment to `\nullfont` to ignore any text. Inside `\node {..};` the font is then restored using `\pgfinterruptpicture` .. `\endpgfinterruptpicture`

In order to make `\settowidth` work you need add `\pgfinterruptpicture .. \endpgfinterruptpicture` around the content:

```
\settowidth{\somelength}{\pgfinterruptpicture Text\endpgfinterruptpicture}
```

---

It would be even possible to patch the underlying macro in `\settowidth` to add these macros automatically. There are two TikZ macros which change definitions of certain macros (like `\node`, etc.) to the TikZ definition inside a picture and then back again. These can be used to use the redefined version only inside pictures while using the normal one outside:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\normal@settodim\@settodim
\let\tikz@settodim\@settodim
\patchcmd{\tikz@settodim}{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox}{\my@tikz@setbox}{}{}
\def\my@tikz@setbox#1{%
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture #1\endpgfinterruptpicture}%
}
\appto\tikz@installcommands{%
    \let\@settodim\tikz@settodim
}
\appto\tikz@uninstallcommands{%
    \let\@settodim\normal@settodim
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{Test}
\the\mylength

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \settowidth{\mylength}{Test}
    \node{\the\mylength};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively `\pgfmathparse{width("MMMMM")}
\setlength{\mypgVTitleWidth}{\pgfmathresult pt}` does the `\hbox` action for you.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @MartinScharrer and @percusse ! I believe also, now that I know [how](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56407/2595) to "save" lengths from local groups for later with `\edef` - the same could be used to measure widths before descending to the `tikz` environment. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Please also see my update where I show how to automate this.

Comment: Thank you! This should be a library or a package or something.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the OP has other needs for *etoolbox* package, but the following solution doesn't need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\sda@ltx@settodim\@settodim
\protected\def\sda@settodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture{#3}\endpgfinterruptpicture}%
  #2#1\@tempboxa\setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
}
% If you're wary of LaTeX's \g@addto@macro, then use:
\protected\def\l@addto@macro#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \toks1\expandafter{#1}\toks@{#2}%
  \edef#1{\endgroup\edef\noexpand#1{%
    \noexpand\unexpanded{\the\toks1 \the\toks@}}}#1%
}
\l@addto@macro\tikz@installcommands{\let\@settodim\sda@settodim}
\l@addto@macro\tikz@uninstallcommands{\let\@settodim\sda@ltx@settodim}

% Alternative. No need to pre-declare a dimension when calling the following:
\def\tikzsetcmdtoheight{\tikz@cmd@settodim\ht}
\def\tikzsetcmdtodepth {\tikz@cmd@settodim\dp}
\def\tikzsetcmdtowidth {\tikz@cmd@settodim\wd}
\protected\def\tikz@cmd@settodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\pgfinterruptpicture{#3}\endpgfinterruptpicture}%
  \edef#2{\the#1\@tempboxa}\setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
}
\makeatother

\newlength\mylength
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \settowidth{\mylength}{Test}
  \tikzsetcmdtowidth\cmda{Test}
  \draw (0,0) node(a) [draw] {{\tt\string\mylength} result: \the\mylength}
    (1.5,1.5) node(b) [draw] {{\tt\string\cmda} result: \cmda};
  \draw[color=red] (a.east) -| (5,1.5) -| (b.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Another approach. No need to pre-declare a dimension when calling the following commands. And no need to load *etoolbox* package. The commands can be used inside and outside of `\tikz`, and even when *tikz* isn't loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\setcmdtoheight{\cmd@settodim\ht}
\protected\def\setcmdtodepth{\cmd@settodim\dp}
\protected\def\setcmdtowidth{\cmd@settodim\wd}
\def\cmd@settodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \@ifundefined{pgfpictureid}{{#3}}{%
      \pgfinterruptpicture{#3}\endpgfinterruptpicture
    }%
  }%
  \edef#2{\the#1\@tempboxa}\setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
}
\makeatother

% For comparison later, let us set \mylength:
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{Test}

\begin{document}
\def\print#1#2{Value of {\tt\string#2}: \if#1c\the\fi#2}
\setcmdtowidth\cmda{Test}
Outside {\tt\string\tikz}:\par
\print c\mylength, \print n\cmda
\par\bigskip
Inside {\tt\string\tikz}:\par\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcmdtowidth\cmda{Test}
  \draw (0,0) node(a) [draw,color=red,rounded corners=5pt] {\print c\mylength}
    (1.5,1.5) node(b) [draw,color=blue,rounded corners=5pt] {\print n\cmda};
  \draw[color=red] (a.east) -| (5,1.5) -| (b.east);
  \draw[color=blue] (a.west) -| (-4,1.5) -| (b.west);
  \fill [gray!25!purple!25](5,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm, rotate=30];
  \fill [gray!25!red!25](-4,1.5) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm, rotate=30];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that example, @AhmedMusa - indeed, `etoolbox` was there for other needs (I just put it in there, unsure if it was maybe a cause of a problem). Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: The `\tikz@installcommands` etc. can be redefined globally without any issue. I was originally going to redefine `\@settodim` myself like you did and using `\g@addto@macro` for the un-/install macros but then decided to go for a more "user-friendly" approach. But it's good to have the direct approach as well.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment by @egreg, I tracked down the post "[How can I use an hbox inside a TikZ environment for text dimension measurement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/how-can-i-use-an-hbox-inside-a-tikz-environment-for-text-dimension-measurement)" which is nearly the same. [The answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18606/2595) explains about `nullfont`, and proposes a `\let\origselectfont\selectfont...` method for having font-based text box width measurement withing `tikz`.

For my second problem - what seems to work, is to "convert" the "length" "type" in `mypgVTitleWidth` to "string" using `\edef`; but that will still cause a local change - unless prepended by `\global`. So now I have the following snippet:

```
....
\def\txxx{INIT}

{
  \fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
  \settowidth{\mypgVTitleWidth}{MMMMM}
  \typeout{ = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }
  \global\edef\txxx{\the\mypgVTitleWidth} % "length to string"
  \setbox\tbxa\hbox{{MMMMM}}
  \typeout{ = D2: \tbxa is \the\wd\tbxa, \txxx }
}


\typeout{ = D3: \tbxa is \the\wd\tbxa, \txxx }
\setlength{\mypgVTitleWidth}{\txxx} % "string to length"

\begin{tikzpicture}
\typeout{ = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is \the\mypgVTitleWidth }
....
```

which seems to work for me:

```
 = C: \mypgVTitleWidth is 45.83344pt
 = D: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
 = D2: \tbxa is 105.74562pt, 105.74562pt
 = D3: \tbxa is 53.83278pt, 105.74562pt
 = E: \mypgVTitleWidth is 105.74562pt
```

Well, ... I hope I understood this right `:)`,
Cheers!

PS: also nice reads:

- [macros - Detecting \global, \long, \outer, \protected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15648/detecting-global-long-outer-protected)
- [tex core - What is the plain TeX equivalent of \settowidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52861/what-is-the-plain-tex-equivalent-of-settowidth)