# Macro with \afterassignment syntax?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Say for some reason I want to make a macro with input stream behaviour mimicking that of `\afterassignment` and `\aftergroup`. Namely, I want to absorb *exactly one* token from the input stream following the macro, without expanding it, regardless of whether it would be an unmatched brace, and store it somewhere I could look at it. This is almost like `\[future]let` but not quite: consider

```
\def\x{\message{Wrong}}
\afterassignment\x
\def\x{\message{Right}}

\def\save{\let\recall=}
\def\x{\message{Wrong}}
\save\x
\def\x{\message{Right}}
\recall
```

which outputs “Right Wrong”.

Comment: I admit I am a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve, and the relevance of your code. It is also a bad code for diagnostic purposes, because it reuses the same strings. I replaced your Wrong, Right, Wrong, Right by AAA, BBB, CCC, and DDD, and found that it outputs BBB CCC. What would you have expected, and why?

Comment: @Harald If I am (e.g.) to hook `\afterassignment` in a useful manner, I should be able to define `\save` so as to get BBB DDD instead. The current behaviour is totally expected, but it is not the desired one.

Comment: It is exactly the purpose of `\futurelet`: `\futurelet\decide\x` will expand `\decide`, that can do things depending on what's the following token (in this case `\x`. Such an action might also include removing the token from the input stream, for example if the replacement text of `\decide` ends with `\let\forget= `.

Comment: @egreg It doesn’t work, unfortunately, although it comes close. (I assume you meant `\futurelet\next\decide\x` or similar.) It inherits its semantics from `\let`. So, `\next` will be defined to be equivalent to the current meaning of `\x`, *not* to expand to `\x`. If `\x` is redefined later, `\next` won’t pick up the redefinition. This is what the example in the question shows.

Comment: you last comment implies the question is not answerable I think, if you want to absorb a left brace you have to use something like `\let` not `\def` as you can not have a mis-matched brace in a macro replacement text.

Comment: @alex-shpilkin Yes, `\next` was obviously missing. You're giving contradictory requirements, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg Well, the point is that there are primitives that work like this, but apparently they cannot be overriden reusably. This means [saving prefixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15648/) cannot be made compatible with `\afterassignment`.

Comment: @alex-shpilkin I don't follow, sorry.

Comment: @alex-shpilkin "if `\x` is redefined later" can only happen from `\decide`. `\decide` examines `\next` and could alter the meaning of `\x` (if it is a macro), but then obviously it knows what it is doing, no ? Note also  that if the token is a character token its catcode will be frozen by the `\futurelet`, it can not be changed from within `\decide`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of `\save` that does everything except distinguish explicit and implicit braces. (Which I think is not possible and is not necessary anyway for customizing `\afterassignment`.) Turns out this is actually quite easy. I use `\global` because that is how `\afterassignment` works, but it’s not essential.

```
\def\save{\futurelet\next\s@ve}
\def\s@ve
 {\ifx\next\bgroup \let\next=\s@veopn
  \else\ifx\next\egroup \let\next=\s@veclo
  \else \let\next=\s@vetok \fi\fi\next}
\def\s@veopn  {\global\def\recall{\iftrue {\else}\fi} \let\next=}
\def\s@veclo  {\global\def\recall{\iffalse{\else}\fi} \let\next=}
\def\s@vetok#1{\global\def\recall{#1}}
```